# Return all rows after Aggregator - Informatica Powercenter

Tags: sql, group-by, netezza, informatica

IMAGE  -

[image: Input, Scenarios and expected output]

Please refer to the image for better understanding of the scenarios
- For input from table I have 5 columns COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5
- Scenario 1, 2, 3, 4 explains the types of input I will receive. The Value in Col 4 can vary(for example 31-35 or 36-39 for same value in Col1)
-The column SUM is summation of values for all numbers in VALUE column of each scenario, and that has to be populated in all the rows. Like 50 in each cell for Scenario 1 under Column (SUM)

The requirement -
Summation to get the Value ex- 50 and then display all the rows (3-20) + Column G in the out put table
So input table has 17 rows 5 Columns(B,C,D,E,F) Output should have 17 rows 6 columns(B,C,D,E,F,G)

I could do the summation by grouping and using aggregate transformation in Informatica but I cannot display all the rows as grouping returns one row.

Comment: On what basis you need to sum the values

Answer (score 1):

Do an aggregated sum based on the columns B, C, and D and then use a  Joiner transformation to join your aggregated output (4 rows) with original source rows (17 rows). Do not forget to use sorted input in the joiner, which is mandatory for this kind of self join.

```
Source ------> Sorter ----> Aggregator -----> Joiner ----->Target
                |                                ^
                |________________________________|
```

Configure the joiner for normal join on the columns B, C and D

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the `SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY COL1, ..., COLN) AS ValueSum` analytical functionality in Netezza? All you need to do is to define how to partition the sums.

Read more here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/c_dbuser_report_aggregation_family_syntax.html